# Adding ID and Class on template dynamically using backbone views

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I want to add a ID and CLASS attribute to my view template.
this is what i tried but failed.

```
$("#login").html( _.template( LoginTemplate ) );
        this.loginmodel = new LoginModel();
        this.loginview = new LoginView({
            el: $("#loginContainer"),
            model: this.loginmodel,
            className: "test"
        });

<div id="loginContainer">
    <div id="loginForm">
      <input class="user-input formContainerInput" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required"/>
      <input class="user-input formContainerInput"  id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required="required"/>
      <a class="connection-btn" data-role="button">Connection</a>
      <a class="login-btn" data-role="button">Log In</a>
    </div>
```

I want to assign id and class using the views and not on the html itself. How will i do it?

## update

attemp #1

```
loginview: function(){
    $("#login").html( _.template( LoginTemplate ) );
    this.loginmodel = new LoginModel();
    this.loginview = new LoginView({
        id: "#loginContainer",
        model: this.loginmodel,
        attributes:{ id:'Test', class: "myClass otherClass" }
    });
},
```

it even display an error in aptana on the "class" part.

even tried it on the main view since the code above was the parent view.

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click .login-btn": "Login",
        "click .connection-btn": 'Connect',
    },
    initialize: function(){
        //some code here
    },
    attributes: {
        id:"test"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about using [View.attributes](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-attributes).

You can specify something like:

```
attributes: {
  id:     "myId",
  class:  "myClass otherClass"
}
```

I didn't try but maybe you also can use `functions` to make it even more dynamic:

```
attributes: {
  id:     function(){ return "element-" + this.id; },
  class:  "myClass otherClass"
}
```

Beware this only affects to the `view.el` DOM element.. not any of its children.

#### Updated

The above solution only works when the `View.el` is anonymous.

So, the only solution I see can work in your concrete scenario is to manipulate the `View.el` directly by JavaScript in the `initialize()` like this:

```
initialize: function(){
  this.$el.attr( "id", "my-id" );
  this.$el.attr( "class", "myclass1 myclass2" );
},
```

[Check the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/sxh4F/) for three different scenarios manipulating the `View.el` attributes.

Comment: just would like to update. it doesn't work if i don't specify id on the div.